# Lightning page assignment in a managed package

Tags: lightning-apps

I have a custom lightning record page assigned to a specific record type. However, it seems the page assignment is not transferred after installation.
I tried to include profile settings in the package but no luck.

Is this supported ?

Comment: Which assignment? App default? IIRC page layout assignments in classic do not carry over either unless you include profiles in the package and the user installs and applies this profiles vs install for all users/admin

Comment: Hello @Frank Stevens. Did you find a solution for assignment lightning pages in a managed package? We have the profile in the packaging org and we see the lightning page. When we install the package and assign the profile to a custom profile, this profile don't see the package page for Accounts and Contacts. Thanks!

Comment: Frank,  @RobertinhoSedinho
Were you able to add Lightning page - assignments to Managed Package? 
Thanks.
Thanks, Sriram

Comment: Hello @Sriram. No, for now, we always do the configuration after the installation manually.