# How to include Record Page and Page Layout assignment into a 2GP Managed Package?

Tags: managed-package, page-layout, 2gp, lightning-record-page

I have a `Managed Package` which contains both `Record Page` and `Page Layout`.

But once installed, neither are assign to corresponding `App` and `Record Type`

Is it possible to include these assignments into a `Managed Package` and for them to be automatically enabled, or does this have to be a post-install manual step?

Looking online, it seems it's manual at the moment, but I wanted to check?

- [Lightning page assignment in a managed package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180489/lightning-page-assignment-in-a-managed-package) has no answer

and

- [Idea: Lightning Record Page activation should be available via Metadata API](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cLetQAE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a manual process. You cannot assign Page Layouts to a Profile in a package, or Record Page overrides. This design limitation allows administrators to choose which layout to use in the event of multiple packages on the same object with different page layouts. It's unlikely they'll ever allow this, as it could overwrite system configurations that the Administrator had already previously configured.

Comment: Could I use an `InstallHandler` to do it after install?

Comment: @Robs Probably, but I would advise against it. Generally speaking, you don't want to clobber a subscriber's setup. At best, you might include a Visualforce page to allow an administrator a one-click option instead.